# Write a query to get the details of all drugs whose price is above the average price of all drugs of the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

as the question say im having an error with this code:

```
select *, avg(price) as average 
from drug 
having avg(drug.price) > (select count(price) from drug)
```

kindly help me.

Comment: Missing group by?

Comment: When using aggregation (sum, min, max, avg) it is generally wise to group by the non-aggregated fields in the select.  While mySQL lets you get away without them (due to the extended group by it implements), the engine is free to choose any value for each of the columns not listed in the group by and display it.  So since you don't have a group by it could display any drug name; and it could change what it picks on subsequent runs as data changes.  In addition this type of syntax would not be supported in Oracle, DB2, SQL Server and many other RDBMS.

Comment: what are you expecting this line to return `select count(price) from drug`?  Why would you compare against the count of rows with prices?

Comment: i just need to know how can i get the average of the rows that have the same type of drug for example antibiotics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know which kind of database you are using, I wrote here in generic -

```
select a.* 
 from drug a
 where a.price > ( select avg(b.price) from drug b where b.type= a.type)
```

Comment: thank you so much this worked as intended i appreciate your help and everyones help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most performant solution but this is how I would approach it:

```
WITH avg_by_type AS (
SELECT type, avg(prive) as avg_type
FROM drug
GROUP BY type
)
SELECT *
FROM drug 
INNER JOIN avg_by_type ON avg_by_type.type = drug.type AND avg_by_type.price < drug.price
```

Comment: how could this be voted up this answer is not going to work on a MySQL server.... MySQL doesnt support windows functions like WITH AS...

Comment: I have posted questions before for PostgreSQL but answers for other extensions have given me the insight needed to approach the solution. It's easy enough to find equivalent syntax based upon certain functions only available to a particular extension.